# How to get curl to decode these &#118; characters into UTF-8 or ascii

Tags: php, curl, decimal, decode

I'm using `cURL` to extract data from a website 
like this:

```
function get_data($url)
{
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 7;
$userAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
}
```

curl returns the exact characters as "`&#118;&#110;&#101;&#110;&#x6E;&#x61;`" which the browser would display as "vnenna".

The question is: how to find these chars and reformat the content to display it properly?

Comment: A better question is: "How can I use curl to correctly interpret "HTML Entities" into regular ascii characters?"  Here is info about what these HTML entities are: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

Comment: Possible Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255531/php-function-to-convert-from-html-codes-to-normal-chars

Answer (score 3):

This is not a cUrl problem. What you see are merely HTML entity encoded charaters. Use `html_entity_decode()` to decode them.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: thank you, that works!
just modified $data = html_entity_decode(curl_exec($ch));